# Как грамотно починить "сломанные" / переставшие работать модули Python?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

Все чаще появляются вопросы о "сломанных" / несовместимых / переставших работать модулях в Python и о сопутствующих этому ошибках:

- `ImportError: DLL load failed: ...`
- `ImportError: Could not import ...`
- `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: ...`

и много других...

Описанные выше проблемы чаще всего возникают вследствие:

- установки нового модуля
- обновления Python
- обновления модуля / модулей
- обновления / изменения в VirtualEnv (виртуальной среде Python)
- неправильного использования `conda` - например если использовать созданное по умолчанию виртуальное окружение `base` (оно используется `conda` для управления остальными вирт. окружениями), вместо явно созданного нового виртуального окружения

### Вопрос:

> как исправить данные проблемы и как избежать их появления в будущем?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

После долгого "хождения по граблям" (как под UNIX* так и под Windows) я остановился на следующем подходе, который меня пока ни разу не подводил.

Основная идея в установке пакета Anaconda и создании независимых виртуальных окружений при помощи менеджера пакетов `conda`.

Anaconda проверяет совместимость версий модулей (включая зависимости). Это минимизирует вероятность поломать Python, просто установив или обновив некий модуль(и).

Алгоритм установки Anaconda и создания `VirtualEnv` (независимого виртуального окружения Python):

1. [Устанавливаем Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/) или [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)

- [Installing on Windows](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/)
- [Installing on Linux](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/)
- [Installing on macOS](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/)

2. Обновляем менеджер пакетов `conda` (**NOTE:** чтобы избежать проблем - всегда запускайте `conda` из `Anaconda Prompt`):

   ```
    conda update conda
   ```
3. Никогда "не трогайте" Python, установленный по умолчанию в ОС или установленный другим программным обеспечением (например при установке Oracle Database, устанавливается отдельный Python, который будет использоваться Oracle).
   Под `"не трогайте" Python` я подразумеваю внесение любых изменений, затрагивающих Python или его модули:

- установка новых модулей
- обновление Python
- обновление модулей

4. Не утсанавливайте модули в виртуальную среду `base` созданную по умолчанию. Устанавливайте модули только в те виртуальные среды, которые вы явно создали (см. следующий пункт - `5`). Виртуальное окружение `base` - это техническое окружение созданное `conda` для управления остальными виртуальными средами. Если не хотите сломать сразу все виртуальные окружения не трогайте `base`.
5. Для каждого более или менее независимого проекта на Python создавайте независимое виртуальное окружение (VirtualEnv). Можно дополнительно создать одно общее окружение для общих целей. В данном примере я создам общее окружение с названием `ml` (Machine Learning) для версии `Python 3.7` и основным набором модулей для работы над задачами машинного обучения (с поддержкой Nvidia GPU):

   ```
    conda create --name ml python=3.7 anaconda keras-gpu
   ```
6. Для того чтобы запустить `Python` / `Jupyter` / `iPython` / etc. из созданного VirtualEnv можно воспользоваться одним из следующих варантов:

- запустить `Anaconda Prompt` --> активировать в нём нужное вирт. окружение (`conda activate <env_name>`) --> запустить `ipython` / `Jupyter-Notebook`
- использовать CMD / shell скрипт для запуска `ipython` из нужного вирт. окружения:

  ```
        @echo off
        set conda_dir=%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3
        set env_name=%1
        if "%env_name%"=="" set env_name=ml
        set env_dir=%conda_dir%\envs\%env_name%
        rem cd %env_dir%
        call %conda_dir%\Scripts\activate.bat %env_dir%
        %env_dir%\Scripts\ipython.exe

    Пример вызова: `c:\bin\ipy_env.cmd ml37`
  ```
- использовать CMD / shell скрипт для запуска `Jupyter-Notebook` из нужного вирт. окружения:

  ```
        @echo off
        set env_name=%1
        if "%env_name%"=="" set env_name=ml
        set env_dir=%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\envs\%env_name%
        rem cd %env_dir%
        call %USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat %env_dir%
        start cmd.exe /k "%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\envs\%env_name%\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe"

    Пример вызова: `C:\bin\jupyter_env.cmd torch`
  ```
- для проекта в PyCharm можно в качестве `Project Interpreter` указать существующий `Conda Environment`

7. Чтобы установить новый модуль всегда попробуйте сделать это в следующей последовательности:

- сначала всегда пробуем найти нужный модуль в репозитори Anaconda по умолчанию

  ```
        conda search <module_name>
  ```
- если модуль найден - устанавливаем его в наш `VirtualEnv` (`ml` в нашем примере):

  ```
        conda install -n ml <module_name>
  ```
- если модуль не найден, то пытаемся найти данный модуль в репозитории `conda-forge` (A community-led collection)

  ```
        conda search -c conda-forge <module_name>
  ```
- если модуль найден - устанавливаем его в наш `VirtualEnv` (`ml` в нашем примере):

  ```
        conda install -c conda-forge -n ml <module_name>
  ```
- только в том случае, если нужный модуль не найден ни в оригинальном Anaconda репозитории ни в `conda-forge` - используем `pip install`:

  ```
        conda activate ml
        pip install <module_name>
  ```

8. чтобы обновить модуль используйте менеджер пакетов `conda`:

   ```
    conda update -n ml <module_name>
   ```

---

Полезные ссылки:

- [Conda Tutorial](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)
- [Conda Cheat Sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/cheatsheet.html)

Comment: У меня с `venv` возникала только проблема обновления системного `python`. Решалось: `python3 -m venv venv_dir && venv_dir/bin/pip install --upgrade wheel && venv_dir/bin/pip install --upgrade -r requrements.txt`. Windows не использую, ничего не могу сказать.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, повторюсь: __не надо трогать системный Python__. "Minor" версию Python можно обновить в самом `venv`: `conda update --all -n <venv>`

Comment: Я не могу не трогать системный `Python`. Дистрибутив переехал, я переехал. Проблем с увеличением версии `Python` и моим кодом - не возникает. Анаконду использовал на старом компьютере (без `AVX`), чтоб `TensorFlow` руками не собирать. Для меня Анаконда - крайне избыточна. Плюс в продакшене у меня Анаконды нет, а разные версии `Python` - есть. Т.ч. лучше я раньше узнаю о проблеме, чем позже.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, я использую Anaconda, т.к. мне нужны почти все модули входящие в "мета-модуль" `anaconda`. Если Anaconda для вас избыточна - используйте `miniconda`

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, я как об этом и пытался сказать - в идеале ваши Python скрипты / проекты не должны зависеть от __системного__ Python

Comment: Да и `miniconda` мне не нужна. У меня с `-m venv` проблем не бывает. Зачем мне еще один `Python`, пакетный менеджер... У меня системные есть. Обновились? Обнови окружение и все. Я на выходе должен получить пакет `.whl`, `.deb` и `.rpm`, способные без проблем ставиться стандартными установщиками (`pip`, `apt`...). В моем пакете должны быть указаны все необходимые зависимости и требования к версии интерпретатора. Если сообщество `conda` зафиксировало версию моей зависимости из-за ошибки, я этого не увижу, а "пользователи" ушедшего в продакшен `.whl` пакета - увидят (`pip` ее не фиксировал).

Comment: Возможно `conda` хороша на Win, Mac системах. Для разработки под версии, не поддерживаемые системой... Для меня, пока я не могу объявить `conda` зависимостью, она не должна влиять на мой код и ошибки с совместимостью. Ну и не вижу я в ней достаточно плюсов, чтоб потратить пол гига дискового пространства, `SConstruct` переписывать, окружение zsh править (у конды инит криво вставал)... ИМХО больше вреда, а пользы я не вижу (`AVX` теперь на всех моих машинах).

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, это вполне рабочий подход если вы не используете тяжеловесных пакетов на подобие: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pandas, tensorflow, keras, etc. - если устанавливать такие пакеты или пакеты, зависящих от них, то есть немаленькая вероятность сломать совместимость, используя `pip`. Именно это я имел ввиду, написав `После долгого "хождения по граблям"`

Comment: @MaxU А когда Oracle устанавливает python для себя? Это я как то пропустил.

Comment: @0xdb, не знаю на счет последних версий, но при установке Oracle 11x Grid Infrastructure, внутри / под `$ORACLE_HOME` устанавливался Python для использования самим софтом Oracle. Многие скрипты Grid Infrastructure ьыли написаны на Python

Comment: @MaxU, Я этим `numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pandas, tensorflow, keras` пользуюсь. Проблема была только с `tensorflow` и `avx`. Ну и выходные убил на скрипт для установки `CUDA` под `Debian`. Собственно и все. Возможно мне везло. :)

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, ну может быть "бог граблей" вас оберегает или вас еще только ждут все те "приключения" с которыми я уже столкнулся... ;)

Comment: @MaxU Видимо "Бог"... Лет 5 уже на Python пишу более-менее активно. Правда ML занимаюсь меньше года, а их библиотеки наиболее "геморройные", из тех, что я встречал.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, вам наверное пока не приходилось разворачивать Python 3.x проекты  на RedHat Linux 6, который идёт с системным Python 2.x ;-)