# Python 3.7 по умолчанию ломает терминал в Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.7

Как сделать Python 3.7 питоном по умолчанию для Ubuntu 18.04?

Я сделал так:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa
sudo apt install python3.7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

И выбрал Python 3.7. После этого терминал перестал открываться. Пришлось снова выбрать 3.6 и все стало нормально.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не надо трогать системный Python! Никогда!

Рано или поздно вы что-нибудь поломаете.

Установите нужную вам версию Python в директорию доступную другим пользователям и укажите в переменной окружения `PATH` путь к новой версии **до** или **вместо** пути к системному Python.

PS лично я предпочитаю [использовать дистрибутив `Anaconda` или `Miniconda`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002447), доступный для `Unix`, `Windows` и `macOS`

Comment: Поддерживаю. Я как-то хотел заменить `Python 3.6` на `3.7`. Начал с удаления старой версии. А дальше Cool Story... =) Удалилось пол системы и больше она не запускалась :( С тех пор и не трогаю ничего.

Comment: @nomnoms12, я тоже по этим граблям уже прошёл...)

Comment: Не смутило сообщение "Следующие пакеты будут УДАЛЕНЫ" и немаленький список ? :)

Comment: @TotalPusher, на тот момент я был неопытным пользователем Linux, наивно полагавшим, что с новой версией системного Python все будет работать только лучше и быстрее)

Comment: @TotalPusher Мой случай тоже абсолютно идентичен комментарию выше =)