# Ошибка при создании виртуального окружения

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Я уже задавал недавно вопрос о том как поставить Python3.7 на Ubuntu.

[Python 3.7 по умолчанию ломает терминал в Ubuntu 18.04](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004899/python-3-7-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b2-ubuntu-18-04)

В итоге я просто переустановил систему и поставил Python3.7 не заменяя им системный. Соответственно, теперь я могу запустить 2 питона - `python3` и `python3.7`.

Теперь я хочу создать виртуально окружение для Python3.7. Запускаю команду

```
python3.7 -m venv venv
```

Получаю ошибку:

> The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip
>   is not available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the
>   python3-venv package using the following command.
>
> ```
> apt-get install python3-venv
> ```

При попытке установить этот пакет возникает ошибка зависимостей. Но я попробовал сделать так:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-venv
```

Пакет установился. Однако ошибка при поптке создать виртуальное окружение не исчезла. Что делать?

Comment: Установите [Miniconda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002448/211923) и забудьте о проблеме

Comment: @MaxU это подойдет для работы с Django?

Comment: Это подойдёт для всего

Comment: А какая конкретно ошибка зависимостей? Допустим, `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 /bin/sh -c 'apt -qq update && apt install -qqy python3-venv python3.7-venv && python3.7 -m venv myenv && myenv/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable);print(sys.version)"'` бежит без ошибок.