# Как установить python 3.8 на ubuntu mate?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.6

В системе уже стоят две версии python 2.7.17 и python 3.6    Как установить версию 3.8. отдельно, чтобы переключаться или обновить версию 3.6? Не ломая системы. Либо с установкой в siblime.

Comment: [связанный вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002447/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8-python)

Comment: MaxU  мне не интересен ни Anaconda ни VirtualEnv, я рассматриваю возможность обновления либо установки Python в уже существующей системе.

Comment: @ruben Если Вас не устраивает `Conda`, то пишите как обычно: `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get install python3.8`.

Comment: @ruben, OK, тогда ждём от вас новых вопросов - как починить системный Python ;)

Comment: MaxU кроме  Anaconda, которой у меня нет в продакшене, а разные версии Python есть, я пока не могу объявить conda зависимостью, и она не должна влиять на мой код и ошибки с совместимостью. Ну и не вижу я в ней достаточно плюсов, чтоб потратить пол гига дискового пространства. Даже pyenv выглядит вариантом получше.

Comment: @nomnoms12  3.8 установился, но как установить pip для этой версии? сейчас pip3 установлен для 3.6.9 и команда python3 --version3.6.9

Comment: @ruben Использовать `pip` нужной версии можно так: `python3.8 -m pip`.

Comment: @nomnoms12  эта ком. выдает просто лист опций commands и options, а нужно установить pip в эту версию 3.8 ведь. Пробовал sudo apt install python3.8-pip - нет пакета

Comment: @ruben `pip` уже установился с `Python 3.8`, его не нужно устанавливать отдельно. По команде, которую я привёл выше, Вы видите аргументы команды `pip`. Если Вам нужно установить какой-то модуль в `Python 3.8`, делайте это так: `python3.8 -m pip install module_name`, где `module_name` — название необходимого модуля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как установить `Python 3.8`?

Введите в терминале:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

> Как установить `pip` для этой версии?

Он устанавливается автоматически вместе с `Python`. Воспользоваться им можете так:

```bsh
python3.8 -m pip
```

---

Пример установки модуля в `Python 3.8`:

```py
python3.8 -m pip install module_name
```

где `module_name` — название необходимого модуля.