# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Уже третий день пытаюсь начать что-то делать в jupyter notebook, но постоянно были какие-то проблемы. Изначально не мог выбрать kernel. Кое-как разобрался поискав в интернете, но сейчас опять появляется ошибка с win32, когда я пытаюсь подключить какую-либо библиотеку. Попробовал все что нашел в интернете, кучу раз переустановил и питон, и анаконду.[image: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32]

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить Anaconda как показано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002447/211923)

Comment: Возможно я что-то не так делаю, но вышло то же самое

Answer (score 0):

У меня было такое когда я создал виртуальное окружение для проекта на версии 3.9, потом удалил питон 3.9 и поставил питон 3.10.
Соответственно, проект не запустился.
Ошибку помогла решить повторная установка версии 3.9 и соответственно удаление версии 3.10.

Comment: А, да, там есть забавный баг, когда при лексикографическом сравнении версия питона 3.10 плучается "младше" чем 3.9