# После обновления anaconda keras перестал работать

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

Обновил conda и после попытки запустить ИНС вылезли некоторые ошибки. Не знаю почему, но стала использоваться Theano в качестве бэкэнда, хотя прописан Tensorflow

Текст ошибки:

> D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
>     from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>   Using Theano backend.
>   WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
>   D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py:560: UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandatory
>     warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."
>   WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
>   WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.

А после того как я попоробовал conda install m2w64-toolchain то вообще все сломалось.
Как решить данную проблему?
Спасибо.

Comment: советую сделать так, как это описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002447) ;) PS советую обратить особое внимание на пункт 4 в ответе

Comment: Спасибо. Я почитал, однако, как я понял, то это действие должно было быть сделано в то время, когда все работало? =) Я попробовал переустановить conda, с keras и tensorflow, однако имею ошибку при попытке импортировать tensorflow "ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль." Ошибка того типа, что указана в вашей ссылке. Есть ли возможность запустить без venv, а то пока я еще не разобрался? Или надо сделать venv и все заработает? Спасибо.

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе все команды “conda ...”, которые вы использовали при установке? Это поможет воспроизвести проблему

Comment: К сожалению, я по началу не обратил особого внимания. Подумал, что это просто минорное обновление версии, но, видимо, это оказалось критической ошибкой.

Comment: Переустановил анаконду полностью. Вроде как сделал venv, активировал, пытаюсь из Anaconda Promt запустить jupyter notebook но не выходит
(OMP) C:\Users\Александр>jupyter-notebook - таким образом
Текст ошибки:
"jupyter" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: [обновил пункт. 6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002448/211923)

Comment: Да, я к этому и пришел.