# Проблема с установкой OpenCV на Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Пытаюсь установить `OpenCV` в `PyCharm` (версия `Python 3.8`, pip обновлен до версии `20.1.1`). Выдает следующий комуникат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В документации написано, что данная проблема может возникнуть в связи со старой версией pip, что исключено:

- Q: Pip fails with `Could not find a version that satisfies the
  requirement ...`?
- A: Most likely the issue is related to too old `pip`    and can be
  fixed by running `pip install --upgrade pip`.

С версиейй Python тоже вроде все отлично:

`Supported Python versions
Python 3.x releases are provided for officially supported versions (not in EOL).
Currently, builds for following Python versions are provided`:

- 3.5
- 3.6
- 3.7
- 3.8

Как все же можно установить данный пакет ?

Comment: советую создать `conda virtual environment` как указано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002448/211923), установить `OpenCV` при помощи `conda` в `VirtualEnv` и указать в PyCharm в качестве интерпретатора существующий `conda virtual environment`

Comment: у меня есть среда в конде, но когда я импортирую там `OpenCV`, этот пакет до бесконечности устанавливается. Для этого и пытаюсь без condy решить проблему. Может мне надо набраться терпения :)