# Поменять версию python в windows 10

Tags: python, windows

Собственно у меня в системе(win 10) 2 версии python, нужны обе. Как можно их переключать? В ситуации на скрине, почему версию пишет 2.7, а запускается 3.8? Читал что нужно в системных переменных PATH что то поменять, но что именно, толковой информации не нашел.

[image: cmd]

Comment: я бы советовал управлять версиями Python используя [виртиуальные окружения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002447/211923)

Answer (score 7):

Утилита `py` - это лаунчер, который с помощью ключей командной строки позволяет запускать нужную версию Python (из установленных на данном компьютере). Справка по этой утилите:

```
C:\Users\User>py --help
Python Launcher for Windows Version 3.8.1150.1013

usage:
py [launcher-args] [python-args] script [script-args]

Launcher arguments:

-2     : Launch the latest Python 2.x version
-3     : Launch the latest Python 3.x version
-X.Y   : Launch the specified Python version
     The above all default to 64 bit if a matching 64 bit python is present.
-X.Y-32: Launch the specified 32bit Python version
-X-32  : Launch the latest 32bit Python X version
-X.Y-64: Launch the specified 64bit Python version
-X-64  : Launch the latest 64bit Python X version
-0  --list       : List the available pythons
-0p --list-paths : List with paths
```

Т.е., если вам нужно запустить Python 2.7, нужно в командной строке указать `py -2.7` или `py -2` (тогда будет запущен интерпретатор Python самой новой версии из "ветки" 2 из установленных).

Также эта утилита умеет брать версию Python из [shebang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)) строки скрипта: если в начале скрипта написать `#!python2.7`, и запустить скрипт с помощью команды
`py имя_скрипта.py`, то скрипт будет запущен с помощью Python версии 2.7 (или другой версии, которую вы укажете).

См. также:

- Документация: [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)
- [PEP 397 -- Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/)

Comment: Интересно. То есть тут есть выбор: или объявляй кодировку, или объявляй версию запуска?

Comment: причем здесь кодировка?

Comment: @ShamusRezol, на следующей строке после shebang указывайте кодировку, как в [PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding) показано