# Скачивание scikit-learn

Tags: python, mac

Подскажите как установить пакет sklearn на macOS, перепробовал уже все, все время выдает ошибку:

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/05/4jp24y111ml7jsbmwxjm9ywm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ti75nlv5/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1
```

Comment: Все как обычно - сначала устанавливаем Anaconda, потом создаём вирт. окружение и устанавливаем в него все необходимые модули. [здесь подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002448/211923)

Comment: я думаю дело в версии питона. я так же не смог на версию 3.9 натянуть sklearn только под виндой.

Comment: @IvaMuxa, это еще один довод в пользу Anaconda - `conda` проверяет все модули на совместимость перед установкой и сообщает если не удалось найти совместимой версии модуля