# Нужно установить numba, но выдает такую ошибку

Tags: python, numba

```
uilding wheel for numba (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/h8/kmltdg1s3mj3pmyq4wvfwmnm0000gn/T/pip-install-tlnihu6t/numba_5c6008d978a24130b52459ff597c5406/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/h8/kmltdg1s3mj3pmyq4wvfwmnm0000gn/T/pip-install-tlnihu6t/numba_5c6008d978a24130b52459ff597c5406/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/h8/kmltdg1s3mj3pmyq4wvfwmnm0000gn/T/pip-wheel-l0hf39u0
       cwd: /private/var/folders/h8/kmltdg1s3mj3pmyq4wvfwmnm0000gn/T/pip-install-tlnihu6t/numba_5c6008d978a24130b52459ff597c5406/
```

Comment: Это точно полный текст ошибки?

Comment: Советую [установить Anaconda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002448/211923) и потом уже спокойно устанавливать нужные модули используя менеджер пакетов “conda”

Comment: Anaconda установлена, как мне устанавливать через conda а не через Пип