# Numpy ошибка установки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pip

Возникают ошибки при установке `numpy` и `pandas`.

`RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program`. Пробовал установку через `.whl` файлы, скачал `gcc` компилятор и добавил в `path`, установил `visual studio build tools`, `pip` обновлен. Система `windows 10 x64`, `python 3.8.1`, `PyCharm` последней версии, установить пытаюсь в `venv`, на всю систему ставится без проблем.
Устанавливаю через `pip3 install numpy --upgrade`

Comment: [установите Anaconda и создайте виртуальное окружение...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002447/211923)

Comment: Так у вас устанавливается или нет? Покажите все команды, как вы создавали `venv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пишите что-то удивительное. `numpy` ставится легко и непринуждённо.

Вот пример. Windows 10, Powershell 7, Pyhton 3.9. Я делаю следующее:

1. Создаю `venv`
2. Активирую `venv`
3. Убеждаюсь, что python указывает внутрь `venv`
4. Запускаю python, делаю `import numpy` и получаю отлуп: `No module named 'numpy'`
5. Устанавливаю `numpy` через `pip` внутри `venv`. Никаких ошибок.
6. Запускаю python, делаю `import numpy` - работает.

На каком этапе у вас ломается? Покажите весь сценарий.

```
PS:tmp> D:\Software\Python\python -m venv try-env
PS:tmp> .\try-env\Scripts\activate
(try-env) PS:tmp> Get-Command python

CommandType     Name        Version    Source
-----------     ----        -------    ------
Application     python.exe  3.9.4150.… D:\tmp\try-env\Scripts\python.exe

(try-env) PS:tmp> python
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> ^Z

(try-env) PS:tmp> python -m pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from D:\tmp\try-env\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
(try-env) PS:tmp> python -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.20.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\tmp\try-env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(try-env) PS:tmp> python
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ^Z

(try-env) PS:tmp> deactivate
PS:tmp>
```

Дополнительная проверка, что `numpy` есть в `site-packages` внутри виртуального окружения:

```
PS:tmp> ls .\try-env\Lib\site-packages\

    Directory: D:\tmp\try-env\Lib\site-packages

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          2021-04-14    18:54                __pycache__
d----          2021-04-14    18:55                numpy
d----          2021-04-14    18:55                numpy-1.20.2.dist-info
d----          2021-04-14    18:54                pip
d----          2021-04-14    18:54                pip-20.2.3.dist-info
d----          2021-04-14    18:54                pkg_resources
d----          2021-04-14    18:54                setuptools
d----          2021-04-14    18:54                setuptools-49.2.1.dist-info
-a---          2021-04-14    18:54            126 easy_install.py
```

Comment: я создаю проект в пайчарме с виртуальным окружением, далее pip install, далее та ошибка, что я привел

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Я подозреваю, PyCharm живёт своей жизнью, и в нём надо пользоваться [встроенным инструментарием установки пакетов](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: попробовал ваш совет, та же ошибка

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, этого просто не может быть. Удалите python и python launcher, сотрите все оставшиеся пакеты. Установите с сайта python (не из ms store) и попробуйте снова.

Comment: проблема решилась, оказывается был старый pip. Почему то в системе стоит обновленный, а venv стартует с 19 версии